# Is there a word that specifically means 'the delight of experiencing something new'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

And if there isn't, how are new words like this usually invented? (I realise the answer is probably that they're not, but they do occasionally make new words through evolution)

Comment: I don't believe so. The closest thing I can think of is a 'pleasant surprise', but that implies your expectations were not in line with what you experienced.

Answer (score 3):

***Neophilia***

> Definition of NEOPHILIA :  love of or enthusiasm for what is new or
>   novel - *[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neophilia)*

Thus also *neophile*, *neophiliac*

...phile in same fashion as, but as antonym of ...phobe. So *neophobia*: fear or dislike of the new,

Comment: that's the love of the new, rather than the feeling of joy of experiencing a new thing. I imagine Neophiles would experience *word needed* quite often.

Answer (score 1):

**novelty**

the quality of being new, original, or unusual.

"the novelty of being a married woman wore off"

Answer (score -1):

Ammeration - the joy of discovering something new.

derived from the Latin 'ammeratio' meaning wonder / surprise / marvel / astonishment.

Comment: Did you construct this word, or is it attested in dictionaries or other reputable reference works? If the former, this post should be converted to a comment. If the latter, you should add citations / references to those authoritative sources.

Answer (score -2):

How about Eureka?
From wikipedia: "Eureka" (/jʊərˈriːkə/) is an interjection used to celebrate a discovery or invention. It is a transliteration of an exclamation attributed to Archimedes.

Comment: *Eureka* is usually an exclamation made either on finding something one had been looking for, or discovering the answer to a puzzle. I was told at school (about six decades ago) that it meant *I have found it*, and Archimedes was said to have run through the streets naked shouting it, after noting his principle whilst in the bath. The principle was *When a body is totally or partially immersed in a fluid it experiences an upthrust equal to the weight of fluid displaced*.